# MPMediaPlayer playing local file issue

Tags: ios, avfoundation, mpmediaplayercontroller

I have a Video Recording feature of my app which successfully records and save in Documents directory in device ( Which i can access from iTunes when i plug device ). My problem is , I made View UI for playback video with APP which does not access or play.

Here is my video URL = /var/mobile/Applications/C13AB577-FFB2-4814-BD39-A9835A2DAE28/Documents/WO-00604-140428101904.349.mp4

My implementation code is :

```
mediaUrl = [mediaUrl URLByAppendingPathComponent:mediaName];

mediaPlayer.movieSourceType = MPMovieSourceTypeStreaming;

mediaPlayer = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] init];

mediaPlayer.controlStyle=MPMovieControlStyleDefault;

mediaPlayer.contentURL = mediaUrl;

mediaPlayer.shouldAutoplay = YES;

mediaPlayer.controlStyle=MPMediaTypeAnyVideo;

[mediaPlayer prepareToPlay];

[mediaPlayer.view setFrame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 360.0, 480.0)];

[self.view addSubview:mediaPlayer.view];

[mediaPlayer play];
```

mediaURL in debug has that value : http://prntscr.com/3e6ohi

Comment: Make sure your url is initialized like: `NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:filePath] ;`

Comment: @KudoCC if you check the screenshot that i gave link , you can see NSURL comes with full path.

Comment: No, the url should be `file:///var...` format.

Comment: @KudoCC , How i forgot that simple thing ! Now it works like a charm :)

Answer (score 0):

I run successfully with current code, I think you should check your mediaURL:

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *basePath = ([paths count] > 0) ? [paths objectAtIndex:0] : nil;
basePath = [basePath stringByAppendingString:@"/MyVideo.mp4"];
NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:basePath];
mediaPlayer.contentURL = url;
```